# Read numbers from pdf file starting from middle of line in python

Tags: python, pdf

I need to open a PDF file and grab numbers at specific positions within the line using python. I will sum the total of the numbers I need. I am not sure if I will need to convert the PDF to a text file first. I need to know what functions to use to set the cursor at the point I need to read only the data I need. Thanks.

Comment: Reading from pdf is not that simple. You may want to read about `pdf-miner` in python. You will have to extract the text from pdf using some python library and and then process that text.

Comment: The PDF may even contain incomplete or misleading information on which visual glyph corresponds to which Unicode character. In that case your task may become even more difficult or even impossible to implement.